# Accessing directive attributes from nested directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an email module that I'm going to plug into future projects. I have three directives: I have a message-list directive (displays basic information like from, subject and date), a summary directive (clickable links which display only the desired information (e.g. body)), and then a details directive (which displays the full view of the email).

The challenge I am having is trying to put all three together to work with the same data via the controller. Essentially I want to show the top-level directive (the list directive) a model via the controller, and then the information from that model should be available for use in the nested directive views, but I don't want to change the attributes on these nested directives.

list directive ---> summary directive(nested in the list directive) --> detail directive(accessible via click event in the summary directive)

This is the parent directive:

```
messagingApp.directive('MessageList', ['$log', function ($log) {
'use strict';

return {
    templateUrl: 'directives/messagelist.tmpl.html',
    scope: {
        messages: '=',
        fromWho: '=',
        subject: '=',
        date: '=',
        details: '=',
        archiveMessage: '=',
        messageStatus: '=',
        messagePriority: '=',
        markAs: '&',
        checkPriority: '&',
        readMessage: '&'
    }
};
}]);
```

And then in my view, these are the attributes that I want to be passed through to the nested directives (available to all three directives):

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in message.allMessages>
        <message-list messages="msg" message-status="msg.status" message-priority="msg.priority" from-who="msg.from" subject="msg.subject" date="msg.date" details="msg.body" archive-message="archiveMessage(msg)" mark-as="markAs(msg)" check-priority="checkPriority(msg)" read-message="readMessage(msg)"></message-list>
</div>
```

In the template for this directive, I then reference the other directives.

Is there an easy way of doing this? I apologize if this is poorly worded. I am new to Angular and I have been researching this problem for quite some time but with no luck. Perhaps I am wording it incorrectly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have any problems with making it work?

Comment: @KirillSlatin Yes. Only because I do not know how to access the parent directive's attribute values with the nested directive's attributes. For example:
<div ng-repeat="msg in messages">
   <directive-one attr1="msg.from"></directive-one>
</div>

Inside of this directive's view is another directive being called which needs to use attr1. How do I get access to it?

Comment: Providing binding in the nested template the same way you did it on first level. Given `attr1` in `directive-one` has the same name in `scope` it should be bound to nested directive with an attribute `<directive-two attr2="attr1">`

Comment: Although you're not forbidden to do the approach with nested directives, my first idea when I read your question was to avoid nesting directives for such complicated functionality as email list. IMHO there should be a partial for the list and thus directives to show one email can have not isolated scope